# Is there any order in which records are stored in SessionDetails and Conferences Table in Lync Archiving DB?

Tags: lync, lync-2010, lync-2013

[Archiving Database Schema](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd572568%28office.13%29.aspx) states that in the tables SessionDetails and Conferences tables, the column 'SessionIdTime' holds datetime value at which session request is captured by Archiving service.

But, is there any order in which the records are stored in the db?

Say, a session 'S1' starts at 1:00 PM and another session 'S2' starts at 1:05PM. 'S2' ends at 1:10 PM and 'S1' is still on going. I have observed that on ending the session the record is written to DB, so is it possible that details of session S2 is written in db prior to 'S1'?

Is there any way to query these tables, in the order in which the records are stored?

Thanks and Regards,

Arjabh

Answer (score 0):

I *don't know the answer for sure* but I would suggest that they're written in the order that makes most performance sense, rather than to convey any particular business logic.

It's certainly possible that what you're seeing is indeed what's happening, but I wouldn't want to rely on it. There is a SessionEndTime column you could use instead though...